# How to use bootstrap modal with Laravel 9, is there a need to use JS or s.th. else?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert, laravel-9

the modal doesn't even appear when I click the button

```
<button
class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="madal" data-target="#deleteModal">
<i class="bi bi-slash-circle"></i>
</button>

<div  class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "delete" below if you are sure you want to delete this skill.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('deleteSkill', [$Skill->id])}}">delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a need to use JS or s.th. else

Comment: Bootstrap has nothing to do with Laravel itself. And yes, you do need to include JS and relevant CSS for Bootstrap to work. I'd advice reading the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

it sometimes behaves funny when you copy a repeated code you've used before and it works, its best if you always copy the initial modal  code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/